# I don't understand why I get this warning about conversion between signed and unsigned, is my compiler wrong?

Tags: c++, embedded-linux

I have this code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::deque<uint8_t> receivedBytes;
    int nbExpectedBytes = 1;

    if (receivedBytes.size() >= static_cast<size_t>(nbExpectedBytes))
    {
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With -Wsign-conversion, this compiles without warning on my linux laptop, but on the embedded linux on which it's meant to run I get the following warning :

> temp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: temp.cpp:10:33: warning:
> conversion to ‘std::deque::size_type {aka long unsigned
> int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
>
> ```
>  if (receivedBytes.size() >= static_cast<size_t>(nbExpectedBytes))
>                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

I just don't understand:

- I have -Wsign-conversion enabled both on my linux laptop and on the embedded linux, so why do I only get the warning on the embedded linux?
- I'm explicitly casting from `int` to `size_t` (which should not produce a warning because the cast is explicit), then comparing a `size_t` to a `std::deque<unsigned char>::size_type`, so where is the implicit conversion from signed to unsigned that triggers the warning??!

I can't help but think the compiler on the embedded linux is wrong here. Am I missing something?

Edit: On my linux laptop I'm using g++ version 9.3.0, while on the embedded linux I'm using g++ version 6.3.0 (probably not the usual binary since it's an ARM64 architecture)

Comment: `Do stuff and fill the variables` Would you be able to create a full [MCVE] including all the "stuff" and including a short `int main()` and all relevant `#include`s, so others may test your code? What "embedded linux" are you using, or more importantly, what compiler, compiler version and compiler options are you using on your linux laptop and on the embedded linux? Are you sure that `nbExpectedBytes` is not negative before the `while`?

Comment: The mention of `std::deque::size_type` in the message would *seem* to indicate that the implicit conversion is being done for the comparison, not for the `static_cast`. Which would then *suggest* that `size_t` is `int` on that system, which is just plain wrong, I think.

Comment: ... unless it's a "size of size_t" issue: 64-bits on your laptop but 32 bits (same as int) on the embedded system. But still shouldn't be a problem with the explicit cast.

Comment: @KamilCuk I've added compiler info. Whether nbExpectedBytes is negative is besides the point since an explicit cast should silence the warning no matter what the variable actually contains. For the same reason this is already a minimal reproducible example (just put that in a `main()` with `#include <cstdint>` (to have access to uint8_t) and `#include <deque>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *undoubtedly* a bug/error in the embedded compiler. Separating the `static_cast` from the `>=` comparison removes the warning, as can be seen from testing the following code on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), with ARM64 gcc 6.3.0 (linux) selected:

```cpp
#include <deque>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::deque<uint8_t> receivedBytes;
    int nbExpectedBytes = 1;

    // Warning generated ...
    while (receivedBytes.size() >= static_cast<size_t>(nbExpectedBytes))
    {
        break;
    }

    // Warning NOT generated ...
    size_t blob = static_cast<size_t>(nbExpectedBytes);
    while (receivedBytes.size() >= blob)
    {
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Further, the warning also disappears when changing to the (32-bit) ARM gcc 6.3.0 (linux) compiler.